# ServiceStack Serialization and De-serialization

Tags: servicestack

I have been looking through ServiceStack with regards to serialization and de-serialization, but I cannot find the exact answers I need.

My questions are:

1) Are there strict format checking on JSON Readers and if so could they be relaxed?
2) Options for serialization and deserialization JSON and other types?